# When I run Show Databases with Hive，an error was reported

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

```
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Then I went to check the log,the error was found.

```
MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getPassword(Ljava/lang/String;)[C)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8843)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getPassword(Ljava/lang/String;)[C
```

Comment: What version of Hive/Hadoop are you using? `NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` means those two versions are not compatible

Comment: My Hadoop version is 3.1.4,My Hive version is 3.1.2.I used to use Hive when I was learning hive, but recently I tried to connect to hbase and found that Hive doesn't work

Comment: There's also a compatibility matrix for hadoop versions and hbase, but the error is definitely related to only Hive's hadoop client

Comment: The problem was solved the other day.My hadoop3.1.3 is incompatible with hbase1.3.1.